# Spring Data JPA map the stored procedure result to Non-Entity POJO from multiple data source

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, multiple-databases

I have tried to research on a better way  of calling two stored procedures on two different data sources with no luck. Here is my scenario, I have connection to two data sources, each data source with a stored procedure. whenever I annotate one configuration as primary I get the results, the other configuration which is not mapped as primary throws an error

> The given SqlResultSetMapping name [Unknown SqlResultSetMapping
> [Testing]] is unknown

When I set the other configuration for the class calling the stored procedure as primary, It shows results, but when both of them are not set as primary they throw an error

> The given SqlResultSetMapping name [Unknown SqlResultSetMapping
> [Testing]] is unknown

Been stuck for several days. I will appreciate any help.Thank you in advance

my first config for calling the first data source

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "guru.springframework.multipledatasources.model.Card",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "cardEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "cardTransactionManager")
public class Cardonfiguration {

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.card")
        public DataSourceProperties cardDataSourceProperties() {
            return new DataSourceProperties();
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.card.configuration")
        public DataSource cardDataSource() {
            return cardDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                    .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "cardEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardEntityManagerFactory(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
            return builder
                    .dataSource(cardDataSource())
                    .packages(Card.class)
                    .build();
        }

        @Primary
        @Bean
        public PlatformTransactionManager cardTransactionManager(
                final @Qualifier("cardEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cardEntityManagerFactory) {
            return new JpaTransactionManager(Objects.requireNonNull(cardEntityManagerFactory.getObject()));
    }
}
```

my second config for the second data source

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "guru.springframework.multipledatasources.model.member",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "memberEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef= "memberTransactionManager")
public class MemberConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.member")
    public DataSourceProperties zamphiaDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("datasource.member.configuration")
    public DataSource memberDataSource() {
        return memberDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "memberEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean memberEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(memberDataSource())
                .packages(member.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager memberTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("memberEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean memberEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(memberEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }

}
```

my controller for the first data source

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
public class CardReports {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @RequestMapping("/reports/CARD/dailyreport")
    public List<Testing> getDailyAchievements(){
        List<Testing> list;
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("dailyreports", "Testing");
        try {
            // Execute query
            query.execute();
            list = query.getResultList();
        } finally {
            try {
                query.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

my non entity for the first data source

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Testing", classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Testing.class, columns = {
        @ColumnResult(name = "TTEAM_ID", type = Integer.class),
        @ColumnResult(name = "VDATE", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="Days_in_Field", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name= "Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="Cummlative_HH_Reached", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="HH_Reached_for_day", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name ="HHs_Finalised_for_day", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day", type = String.class),
        @ColumnResult(name="HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day", type = String.class)
}))

public class Testing {
    private Integer TTEAM_ID;
    private String  VDATE;
    private String Days_in_Field;
    private String Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH;
    private String Cummlative_HH_Reached;
    private String HH_Reached_for_day;
    private String HHs_Finalised_for_day;
    private String Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day;
    private String Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day;
    private String Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day;
    private String HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day;

    public Testing(Integer TTEAM_ID, String VDATE, String Days_in_Field, String Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH, String Cummlative_HH_Reached, String HH_Reached_for_day, String HHs_Finalised_for_day, String Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day, String Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day, String Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day, String HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day) {
        this.TTEAM_ID = TTEAM_ID;
        this.VDATE = VDATE;
        this.Days_in_Field = Days_in_Field;
        this.Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH = Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH;
        this.Cummlative_HH_Reached = Cummlative_HH_Reached;
        this.HH_Reached_for_day = HH_Reached_for_day;
        this.HHs_Finalised_for_day = HHs_Finalised_for_day;
        this.Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day= Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day;
        this.Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day = Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day;
        this.Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day = Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day;
        this.HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day = HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day;
    }
//getters and setters
```

my second data source controller

```
 @RequestMapping("/api/v1")
    @RestController
    public class MemberDaily {
    
        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;
    
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @RequestMapping("/reports/member/dailyachievementreport")
        public List<DailyReport> getDailyAchievements(){
            List list;
            StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("dailyreports", "Testing");
            try {
                // Execute query
                query.execute();
                list = query.getResultList();
            } finally {
                try {
                    query.unwrap(ProcedureOutputs.class).release();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

how I am mapping results on my pojo for my second data source

```
@MappedSuperclass
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "Testing", classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = Testing.class, columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "TTEAM_ID", type = Integer.class),
            @ColumnResult(name = "VDATE", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="Days_in_Field", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name= "Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="Cummlative_HH_Reached", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="HH_Reached_for_day", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name ="HHs_Finalised_for_day", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day", type = String.class),
            @ColumnResult(name="HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day", type = String.class)
    }))
    
    public class Testing {
        private Integer TTEAM_ID;
        private String  VDATE;
        private String Days_in_Field;
        private String Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH;
        private String Cummlative_HH_Reached;
        private String HH_Reached_for_day;
        private String HHs_Finalised_for_day;
        private String Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day;
        private String Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day;
        private String Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day;
        private String HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day;
    
        public Testing(Integer TTEAM_ID, String VDATE, String Days_in_Field, String Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH, String Cummlative_HH_Reached, String HH_Reached_for_day, String HHs_Finalised_for_day, String Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day, String Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day, String Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day, String HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day) {
            this.TTEAM_ID = TTEAM_ID;
            this.VDATE = VDATE;
            this.Days_in_Field = Days_in_Field;
            this.Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH = Expected_cummilative_Number_of_HH;
            this.Cummlative_HH_Reached = Cummlative_HH_Reached;
            this.HH_Reached_for_day = HH_Reached_for_day;
            this.HHs_Finalised_for_day = HHs_Finalised_for_day;
            this.Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day= Number_of_HH_in_process_for_day;
            this.Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day = Number_of_HH_Refused_for_day;
            this.Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day = Number_of_Revisits_Scheduled_for_day;
            this.HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day = HH_loss_3rd_visit_attempt_refusals_for_day;
        }
    //getters and setters
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `cardEntityManagerFactory` will scan the package of `Card.class` for classes annotated with `@ManagedSuperClass` and
`memberEntityManagerFactory` will scan the package of `member.class`

It looks like you are using the same POJO with `SQLResultSetMapping` "Testing" in both the controllers. But it is not clear in which package this POJO is. So make sure the package of your POJO is scanned by both the entity managers.

Also, You are simply auto wiring the entity manager without specifying name in both the controllers. As per my understanding, only the Primary entity manager will be autowired in both the controllers if you don't specify a `Qualifier`.

I think, you can try with `@PersistenceContext(name = "cardEntityManagerFactory")` and `@PersistenceContext(name = "memberEntityManagerFactory")` in the `CardReports` and `MemberDaily` controllers respectively.

**Update**

I had a look at your GitHub code and found that your `BAISVReports` controller was getting the primary entity manager only. So just autowired the entitymanager using `@Qualifier` as shown below and now the secondary entity manager is getting autowired. Now both controllers are able to find the `SQLResultSetMapping`

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@RestController
public class BAISVReports {

@Autowired
@Qualifier("baisvEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

For more information, refer the [article on How to Configure Multiple Data Sources, Entity Managers, Transaction Managers in Spring Boot](https://www.javachinna.com/spring-boot-multiple-data-sources/)

Comment: I have done as advised, but I end up with the error have shared the code [link](https://github.com/remymumoh/multidatasource)

Comment: how do you specify the `Qualifier` in both controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `SqlResultSetMapping` works on `@MappedSuperclass`. Try to put it on an entity instead.

Comment: Hi @Christian, thank you for your reply, Am using a non entity pojo, kindly advise how I can add the Entity.

Comment: You can add these mappings through an orm.xml file like in this example: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/resources/org/hibernate/test/annotations/query/orm.xml